# Application Exit Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#

I am getting this error Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

I have 3 forms. These are the form closing events of all 3 I did some research and learnt that some from was modified/shown inturn causing this error

Form1

```
private void btnExitl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();   
        }

private void frmPlant_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

     if (DataDirty)
        {
            if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit", "Data Changed", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question))

                 Application.Exit();
            else
                e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else

             Application.Exit();
    }
```

Form2:

```
 private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Close();
    }

    private void frmInputFiles_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        int plantid = StaticClass.GlobalValue;
        //Properties.Settings.Default.PlantId = plantid;

        Program.fPlant = new frmPlant(plantid);

        Program.fPlant.Show();
        e.Cancel = false;
        //this.Hide();
    }
```

Form3:

```
    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void frmVesselData_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {


        DialogResult result;
        int fileId = StaticClass.FileGlobal;
        if (DataDirty)
        {
            string messageBoxText = "You have unsaved data. Do you want to save the changes and exit the form?";
            MessageBoxButtons button = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
            string caption = "Data Changed";
            MessageBoxIcon icon = MessageBoxIcon.Question;
            result = MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon);
            if (result == DialogResult.No)
            {
                Program.fInputFiles = new frmInputFiles(gPlantId, gPlantName);

                    Program.fInputFiles.Show();
                   //e.Cancel=true;

            }
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                //return;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            Program.fInputFiles = new frmInputFiles(gPlantId, gPlantName);
                Program.fInputFiles.Show();
                //e.Cancel = false;

        }      
    }
```

It happens only when I view the third form(Form3). Form1, Form2 work well,. But if I view form3 and try to go back to form1
 So somewhere in the closing event of form3, form1

My guess is the `btnExit_close` event of the form `this.close()`

Thank you

Comment: Your error doesn't appear to be related to the code that you posted.  That error usually occurs when you are looping through a collection via foreach and you try to modify one of the objects in the collection you are iterating.

Comment: Expanding the above comment, it occurs when you modify the contents of the collection you are iterating (adding, removing, or modifying).

Comment: The stack trace of the exception will point you to which collection is the offender.

Comment: Thats what goole pointed towards- a foreach enumerator. I dont have a foreach anywhere. It is something which the form.show. or creating another instance of form somewhere

Comment: This happens because you are showing a new form when the app is trying to shut down.  You'll need to pay attention to e.CloseReason in the FormClosing event handler.

Comment: Thank u. I was able to fix it. added a check on e.closeReason="userClosing"

Answer (score 5):

Simply call  Environment.Exit(0);

Comment: Although this works, it does not trigger the Form_Closing event, so be sure to dispose of any database or message queue connections or any repos or file handles lyng around. Otherwise you will run into a memory leak problems.

Answer (score 4):

While closing your First Form try this on FormClosingEvent

```
    private void frmPlant_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

    if (DataDirty)
    {
        if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit", "Data Changed", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question))
        {
             this.Close();
             Application.Exit();
        }
        else
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
         Application.Exit();
    }
```

Call this.Close() first and then Application.Exit(), Application.Exit() terminates all processes and Close() close your main form